# Clarifying data in Swift for more user friendly results

Tags: swift, set

The result of the func that I show on the label after the button is pressed is a Set.

I change it to String but still the [ ] are left.

The code looks likes this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var fResult:UILabel!

func iterateNremove() -> (Set<Int>, Set<Int>){
    var nums = Set<Int>(1...50)
    var reslts = Set<Int>()
    for _ in 1...5{
        let randNum = nums.randomElement()!
        reslts.insert(randNum)
        nums.remove(randNum)
    }
return (nums, reslts)
}


@IBAction func randomize(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let go = iterateNremove()
    let res = go.1

  let strng = "\(res)"
    
    fResult.text = strng
```

How do I remove the [ ] brackets from the string displayed on the label?
If the answer is obvious but I didn't know the right keyphrases to look for it, please just post the keyphrases, don't " - " the thread...

Comment: Are you looking for [joined(separator:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/1689705-joined)? Something like `fResult.text = res.joined(separator: ",")`

Comment: something like `"\(res.isEmpty ? "" : res)"`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson

I still needed to pass string to the method. I created another constant: strng which was res (Set) changed to String via "/ " call.

Your solution with "strng" constant passed throws an error:
No exact matches in call to instance method 'joined'

Tried to look for similar cases, but couldn't find any.

Thanks for your contribution though :)

Comment: @justintime - your solution didn't change anything, unfortunately. The result still looks the same. It has [ ] brackets around.

Thanks for trying to help out!

Comment: Please give some input and output samples, for us to understand exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to map `Set<Int>` to `[String]` and then call `joined`

```
let strng = res.map(String.init).joined(separator: ",")
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it works perfectly.
Will read documentation to map function.